# How to pass argument to scoring function in scikit-learn's LogisticRegressionCV call

Tags: python, function, arguments, scikit-learn, scoring

**Problem**

I am trying to use *scikit-learn*'s [`LogisticRegressionCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html) with [`roc_auc_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) as the scoring metric.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

clf = LogisticRegressionCV(scoring=roc_auc_score)
```

But when I attempt to fit the model (`clf.fit(X, y)`), it throws an error.

```
 ValueError: average has to be one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples')
```

That's cool. It's clear what's going on: `roc_auc_score` needs to be called with the `average` argument specified, per [its documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) and the error above. So I tried that.

```
clf = LogisticRegressionCV(scoring=roc_auc_score(average='weighted'))
```

But it turns out that `roc_auc_score` can't be called with an optional argument alone, because this throws another error.

```
TypeError: roc_auc_score() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

**Question**

Any thoughts on how I can use `roc_auc_score` as the scoring metric for `LogisticRegressionCV` in a way that I can specify an argument for the scoring function?

I can't find an SO question on this issue or a discussion of this issue in *scikit-learn*'s GitHub repo, but surely someone has run into this before?

Comment: According to the docs you linked to `average` has a default value of "macro", so that shouldn't be causing the error.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why it's asking for a definition of that argument. I thought it might be the version I'm using (`0.16.1`), but the docs for that version show the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem!

*scikit-learn* offers a `make_scorer` function in its `metrics` module that allows a user to create a scoring object from one of its native scoring functions **with arguments specified to non-default values** (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions) for more information on this function from the *scikit-learn* docs).

So, I created a scoring object with the `average` argument specified.

```
roc_auc_weighted = sk.metrics.make_scorer(sk.metrics.roc_auc_score, average='weighted')
```

Then, I passed that object in the call to `LogisticRegressionCV` and it ran without any issues!

```
clf = LogisticRegressionCV(scoring=roc_auc_weighted)
```

Comment: You're on the right path, but have to be a bit careful here. The reason is that I think you might be using the `.predict` method internally. You would need to set `make_scorer(..., needs_proba=True)`. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: Gyan is your solution with roc_auc_weighted  working for you? I don't like idea of creating a hackish def roc_auc_score_proba(y_true, proba), it's having problems when called from Jupiter.

Comment: Oh. Figured it out. Somehow inclusion of needs_proba=True into roc_auc_weighted made it throwing errors. But your example is working fine "as is".

Answer (score 10):

You can use `make_scorer`, e.g.

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# some example data
X, y = make_classification()

# little hack to filter out Proba(y==1)
def roc_auc_score_proba(y_true, proba):
    return roc_auc_score(y_true, proba[:, 1])

# define your scorer
auc = make_scorer(roc_auc_score_proba, needs_proba=True)

# define your classifier
clf = LogisticRegressionCV(scoring=auc)

# train
clf.fit(X, y)

# have look at the scores
print clf.scores_
```

Comment: Yup, discovered `make_scorer`, but the problem was with the `average` argument, the probability extraction piece wasn't actually a part of this problem, but good flag for those who want probabilities rather than binary predictions.

Comment: I understand, yes. I guess I focused on the proba thing because you're using the AUC score (which doesn't make much sense if you don't use probabilities).

Answer (score 2):

A bit late (4 years later). But today you can use:

```
clf = LogisticRegressionCV(scoring='roc_auc')
```

Also, all other scoring keys can be obtained through:

```
from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS
print(SCORERS.keys())
```